# Renaming Attribute in Triggered Send Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, triggered-send

I have an active triggered send data extension. Now, I want to rename one attribute in it. I tried renaming the attribute as we do it for standard/normal data extension, but it failed all the time. can anyone provide me solution in renaming the triggered send data extension.

Comment: Hello Abhi, After renaming the attribute did you pause & republish the Triggered send ??

Comment: No, I am not able to rename the attribute. It simply resets to the previous name as soon as i click on save fields button